# Plotting Method error using PyPlot in IJulia

Tags: matplotlib, julia, ijulia-notebook

I am trying to plot a function using PyPlot on an IJulia notebook, but I keep obtaining error messages.

When I ran this code:

```
function gtest2(x)
    6.34*(log2(1+exp(10.0*(x+0.5))))^0.8
end

using PyPlot
 x = -1.0:0.1:1.0;
plot(x, gtest2(x));
```

I got errors like these:

> MethodError: no method matching ^(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Float64)
>   Closest candidates are:   ^(::Float64, ::Float64) at math.jl:355 ...

I tried to defined a different type of variable while defining my function  using `gtest2(x::Number)` or `gtest2(x::Float64)` but I have the same errors.

It does the same using `linespace` instead of `-1.0:0.1:1.0`. I understand that the format the function sees in input does not match the definition but I don't get what I'm doing wrong because simple functions work:

```
function f(x)
    x
end
plot(x,f(x))
```

Why am I getting those errors in the first case?

I am using IJulia notebook 0.5.1 on safari.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't properly handle vectors thus you need to either change `gtest`
using the `.` vectorization syntax

```
function gtest2(x)
    6.34*(log2.(1 + exp.(10.0*(x + 0.5)))).^0.8
end
```

or even easier use the dot vectorization as follows

```
plot(x, gtest2.(x));
```

To learn more about dot vectorization please see the following in the docs: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/functions.html#man-vectorized-1

Comment: It works perfectly ! i will read the page adviced, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first definition works also with:

```
map(gtest2, x)
```

or

```
gtest2.(x)
```